# What does "You're a stroke of genius" mean?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I was playing Max Payne 3 and this dialogue appeared in one of the cutscenes

> "Wilson Da Silva," replies Max, "You're a stroke of genius!"

Can anybody explain what it means?

Comment: Is it possible they said "You're a stroke of genius!" instead?

Comment: @snailboat Yeah.

Comment: @PurpleXenon Welcome to ELL! You should edit your question to reflect the corrected version of the question, so we may answer your question and not the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Wilson intends to tell Max that Max is quite a genius.  Neither “You are one stroke of a genius” nor “You’re a stroke of genius!” is well phrased; both appear to be [eggcorns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) or [malapropisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) that misuse the common phrase *[stroke of genius](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stroke+of+genius)*,  meaning “an act of genius; a very clever and innovative idea or task” and used when referring to something someone did rather than to a person.  Possibly *stroke* was dubbed into the dialog in place of some vulgar term that was previously there.

Comment: Actually I don't think Wilson is telling Max he's smart at all. I think he's telling him he's a patsy, which is quite the opposite of genius, and that the idea to use Max as a fall guy is what was a brilliant idea. Because of Max's history and recent behavior, no-one will believe his innocence.

Comment: @ColleenV, in other words, not  “You are a genius” but  “Choosing you was a stroke of genius” ?  That might fit with the dialogue as shown in  AlanCarmack's answer but does not fit with it as quoted in the question: «”Wilson Da Silva,” replies Max, “You’re a stroke of genius!”» which shows *Max* calling *Da Silva* a genius, not vice versa

Comment: I think if you look at the conversation as a whole, it makes sense. "What's my part in this?" "You? You are a stroke of genius I had for a fall guy." The question might not have enough context, so I wouldn't say you're wrong. I actually gave you an up-vote for suggesting it might be a replacement for a vulgar word :)

Answer (score 3):

Stroke of genius

> An outstandingly brilliant and original idea.
>   [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stroke-of-genius)

the quotation comes in [an extended dialog](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt1407064/quotes?qt=qt1763824), assuming [IMDB](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt1407064/) is correctly reporting it.

> Max Payne: What about Marcelo?
>   Wilson DaSilva: Marcelo, **Marcelo...  was an idiot.** Were this true, I certainly don't believe he could possibly known about it, but I do believe that some other scheme, you know, some other bullshit, whatever that cash was Victor could have talked into something, I don't know yet.
>   Max Payne: And Passos?
>   Wilson DaSilva: **Raul Passos is a bum ex-cop.**
>   Wilson DaSilva: [gets in his car, along with Max] He failed in America, failed in Sao Paulo, he was surrounded by more money, and more poverty than his tiny little head can handle. You think guys like that can be brought [sic]?
>   Max Payne: No, but if...
>   Wilson DaSilva: But nothing. **He's probrably [sic] not a bad guy.** he's just a man caught in the cross fire of a very rich family.
>   Max Payne: [pauses] What about me?
>   Wilson DaSilva: You? **You're the fall guy.** The American, running around, acting like an action hero, killing lots of people.
>   Wilson DaSilva: [chuckles] **You're a stroke of genius.**
>   Max Payne: That ain't how it is.
>   Wilson DaSilva: You were an angry ex-cop. You were sitting in the bar, with a history of violence, and a history of bad temper. You were perfect.
>   Max Payne: Me and Passos went to the academy together.

(emphasis added)

In this scene, Wilson DaSilva is calling different people different things. And while *stroke of genius* usually applies to an idea, it is used effectively here toward a person. It could be as simple as that. Or it could be that in or for the group, Payne served as a *stroke of genius*.  Both would basically be a metaphor.   Either way, it's an effective application of an idiom toward a person instead of its normal use, toward an idea. This shows the flexibility of language and the creativity that people can put to it.

Or it is possible (but not probable from this passage) that Payne is the personification of another person's *brilliant idea* (*stroke of genius*). Perhaps the person who recruited Payne. But I've not played Max Payne, so this is a guess.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much more common to say

> Your idea was a stroke of genius!

To say that a **person** is "a stroke of genius" is a little odd; if the quote is accurate, it may be comedic or an indication that the character does not have a very good mastery of English.

Answer (score -1):

If you've had a stroke, your mind can be more literal or more empathetic thereafter. A 'Stroke of Genius' is a rewired most brilliant mind.

Comment: Do you have any credible sources to support this? The effects of a stroke are memory loss, partial paralysis, vision problems, speech problems, and others. It doesn't make you more brilliant.